# Outlook 2010 .OST Files and Permission Errors?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2003

Outlook 2010 complained of errors in an OST file, so I made a backup copy of the 9GB file, and used scanpst.exe to try and remedy the issue.

scanpst.exe ran for about an hour and a half and then completed. When I opened Outlook again, first it asked me to select the profile to use, and then I received the following error message:

"Outlook is using an old copy of your Outlook data file (.ost). Exit Outlook, delete the file, and restart Outlook. A new file will be automatically created the next time you initiate a send/receive."

Then Outlook opened. When I clicked Send/Receive, Outlook complained that the permissions on the OST file outlook was using were incorrect.

Re-downloading the OST file will take a pretty long time considering it is 9GB. In the meantime I have sent the user to the webmail on the exchange server, but I am wondering what I should do...should I just delete the OST file and let Outlook recreate it or is there something else I can do to fix this that would require less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the OST and unfortunatley you will wait while it is recreated.  You might ask the user to clean up his Outlook store on the server or archive some items.  That would depend on archiving policies and what the user might want while offline.

Comment: And it won't matter if they are using the web access while it downloads?